# how to make an image work as a check box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, dreamweaver

I am working on phone-gap application in dream-weaver 
I have 2 divs `.pics` and `.cover`

```
<div class="pics">
    <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

the main idea is to change the colour of the cover div and toggle a JS variable between true and false

```
        var checked=false;
$('.pics').click(function(){
    CheckToggle();
});
function CheckToggle(){
    if(checked==false){
        checked=true;
        $('.cover').css({"background":"rgba(255,255,255,.5)"});
    }
    else
        checked=false;
}
```

I click on `.pics` and nothing happens
I think there is an error in the jquery code

**This is what I used after all**

```
$(function(){
    $( "#item1" ).bind( "tap", PicCheck );
        var checked;
        var choosen="#item1";
        checked=$(choosen).attr('pcheck');

function PicCheck( event ){
    if(checked=="false"){
        $(choosen).toggleClass("selected");
        checked="true";
      }
      else if(checked=="true"){
        $(choosen).toggleClass("selected");
        checked="false";
        }
    $(choosen).attr('pcheck',checked);                  
 }
```

});

Comment: Works for me can you create a jsfiddle or show the styling you use.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gqkfcmot/1/, working here. Have you checked your console to see if there are any errors (like syntax errors) in your script. If there are it might be preventing this code from running

Comment: @Patrick Evans but it doesn't work using jquery-mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some css you can implement a checkbox and radio buttons with pictures. Try this :

```
<div>
 <input id="input-1" class="img-checkbox" type="radio" name="selectTipo">
 <label for="input-1" class="">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/128px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png">
 </label>

 <input class="img-checkbox" type="radio" id="input-2" name="selectTipo">
 <label for="input-2">
     <img src="http://www.javatpoint.com/images/javascript/javascript_logo.png">
 </label>
```

And in your css :

```
input.img-checkbox[type=radio], input.img-checkbox[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
img{
    height:100px;
}
input.img-checkbox[type=radio]+label, input.img-checkbox[type=checkbox]+label {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input.img-checkbox[type=radio]:checked+label, input.img-checkbox[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  border: 10px solid #C6ECED;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

See the result in the follow [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6wqrzk8/)

Comment: really cool ! i was searching on how to do it but i didnt find any thing ;-; thx

Answer (score 1):

It is usually most convenient to use additional class for your purpose.
Here is a simple example:

```js
    var checked = false;
    $('.pics').click(function() {
      CheckToggle();
    });

    function CheckToggle() {
      $('.cover').toggleClass('selected');
      checked = $('.cover').hasClass('selected');
    }
```

```css
    .cover {
      background: red;
    }
    .cover.selected {
      background: green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pics">
  <div class="cover">test</div>
</div>
```

*Edit:*
Since you are using jQuery mobie, you might want to try the [vclick](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/) or [tap](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) events instead of the regular `click` event.

Comment: it didn't work in the dreamweaver, i think it has to do with that jquery mobile use different approach

Comment: didn't work :( this the how it should be right ?  $('.pics').on("vclick", function(){
 CheckToggle();
});

Comment: i really want to use your way but i cant make it to work

Comment: Yes `vclick` code seems correct. So there is an JS error pooping up somewhere, or something is blocking the clickable area of your element

Comment: the tap worked after all `$( "#item1" ).bind( "tap", PicCheck );` but it needed to be handled as I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

I'd skip the Javascript and use a `label` element and the `:checked` selector.

```
#example {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
}

label {
  color: purple;
}

#example:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

The HTML would be like this:

```
<input id="example" type="checkbox" name="example" value="true">
<label for="example">Example</label>
```

With this approach you wouldn't need to worry about tracking the `checked` variable and you can just figure it out normally.

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/cirali/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: yes I wouldn't have to about tracking the checked but also i want be using a picture as a check box

Comment: You can use a background image.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how you have the elements styled, it might be better to put the action on the `.cover` element... If the child element `.cover` is the exact same height and width of the parent element `.pics` you wont be able to click on `.pics`

Comment: click events bubble up the dom, so .pics would get an event call if clicked on .cover